# The difference between "C c = new C()" and "A c = new C()" when C is a subclass of A in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Let's say we have class A as a parent class, and class C that extends it.

```
class A
{
    void m()
    {
        System.out.println("A.m");
    }
}

class C extends A
{
    @Override
    void m()
    {
        System.out.println("C.m");
    }
}
```

What's the difference between reference `A a` and `C c` when we use them to point to the same object type, for example `A a = new C();` and `C c = new C();`?

From this question: [Java inheritance vs. C# inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323099/java-inheritance-vs-c-sharp-inheritance), it looks like that as `a` and `c` points to object type of C, and there seems no difference in using them.

I tested this code, and they all prints `C.m`.

```
class inherit {

    void x(A a)
    {
        a.m();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        A a = new C();
        C c = new C();
        a.m();
        c.m();

        new inherit().x(a);
        new inherit().x(c);

    }
}
```

Comment: If `C` defines methods not defined in `A`, you won't be able to call them through an `A` reference. Also if a method expects a `C` argument, you can't pass it an `A`. In both cases you'll have to cast `A` to `C`.

Comment: The difference is, if C had a method that A didn't, it would not be accessible through A a. On the other hand, if you have multiple sub-types of A, and want to treat them all the same for some collection, then casting them as A makes more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends what the object is going to be used for.

If what you actually need is an object that has `A`'s interface(i.e. `A`'s type), it's strongly recommended to use `A a = new C();`. This way it makes it clear that you want an `A` *interface*, not a `C` *implementation*. Later when you change your mind, you can safely change it to `A a = new Another_Subtype_Of_A();` without breaking other code.

This is especially true when `A` is an interface(In your case, `A` is a class). For example, if you just want a list, `List list = new ArrayList();` is clearly better than `ArrayList list = new ArrayList();`. That's called "programming to interface, not implementation".

If you're creating an object that specifically needs `C`'s interfaces(esp. those not present in `A`), you'd better choose `C c = new C();`. If you write `A a = new C()` instead, sooner or later you still have to cast the object to `C`(because A doesn't have all of your desired interfaces), so why bother?

Answer (score 1):

It's not about the runtime type of the variable.  You may only know you have a `Vehicle` object at compile time and based on user input, that may be a `GarbageTruck` or `SportsCar`.

```
GarbageTruck t;
...
t = new SportsCar();  //can't do this!

// so we do this:
Vehicle t;
if(user.isFast()) {
   t = new SportsCar();
} else {
   t = new GarbageTruck();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is all about Interfaces and Implementations.

An Interface is simply a set of public fields (methods & properties) the describe how users can interact with a class that implements the interface.

An Implementation is the code that *actually* makes those methods and properties do something. An Implementation can be a class that `implements` an `interface`, or it could be a subclass of some other implementation.

When you instantiate a class, you're writing code like:

```
Interface a = new Implementation();
```

Often times, we wrap the Interface and the Implementation all together... put another way, when we define a `class`, whether we're explicitly implementing an interface or not, we're defining an Interface with every `public` method we write.

Thus, it's the Interface that affects what methods we can call, but it's the Implementation that affects what happens when we call them.

Answer (score 0):

firstly `A` is parent class and `C` is child class  when you do `A a = new A()` then object of `A` is created and hold by `A` handle. When you do `C c = new C()` then object of`C` is creating and `C` handle holds it.. But when you do `A a = new C()` then object of`C` is created and `A`handle holds it. It means all the properties of`C` is now been used. Although handle of`A` is used by properties (instance) of `C` are used. This us polymorphism. Now it will used all the overloaded methods of C and not of A

**Usages as an example**
The difference come when you create a large project having methods created for child classes
Assume you have `hello` method
`public void hello(C c) { }`

In future you have another class B which extends A.. in that case you cannot use `hello` as its argument is of type C.. And imagine you have many classes as a child of A which need to use such method (then how many such methods you will create). Polymorphism is the rescue
You create hello with A as argument
`public void hello (A x) { }`
and now you can use same method for all the children of `A`..
`A c = new C()

A b =  new B()`
Now all can use `hello`
*this is the beauty of polymorphism*